# With trailing slash in URL , jsp show source code

Tags: wildfly, wildfly-8

we have application deployed over wildfly 8.1 . All works fine for jsps , but whenever I put a slash , browser shows source code of jsp. This is an issue from security.

Can I handle this at wildfly or undertow configuration level .

For example :

localhost:8080/TaskManager/login.jsp/ - show jsp source code

localhost:8080/TaskManager/login.jsp - works perfect

One solution I am aware of is to put all my jsp inside WEB-INF , but I am looking to handle it at server level.

If it possible , if yes how ? Please help

Thanks,
Abhinav

Asked same question at  https://developer.jboss.org/message/927301#927301 but didn't get any response yet.

Comment: I am able to reproduce this issue with wildfly logging quickstart.
If I use URL , http://localhost:8080/jboss-logging/home.jsp(+ slash)  - I see content of jsp..

And http://localhost:8080/jboss-logging/home.jsp and this works fine.

 

Shared war file at https://www.dropbox.com/s/8qbec3n22btg7mf/jboss-logging.war?dl=0

Please have a look once you have some time available .

 

Thanks in advance for helping me here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be a serious issue in the Undertow (web subsystem in the WildFly) - I've reported it in the WildFly issue tracker: **[WFLY-4595](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/WFLY-4595)**

Answer (score 0):

Thanks. Bug is resolved on Undertow master branch.

https://developer.jboss.org/message/927301#927301  look this link for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Servlet filter class have do filter method.
        this method write below code.

```
    Example: 
    String url = req.getRequestURL().toString();
    if(url.endsWith("/"))
       {
    ((HttpServletResponse) response).setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_MOVED_PERMANENTLY);
    ((HttpServletResponse) response).sendRedirect(contextPath + ERROR_PAGE);
    return;
    }
```